# Detect font color from image in android after OCR

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have an image and using tesseract I am finding text from it. 
I have bounding box of the text in the form of rect(left,top,right,bottom)

I want to find the font colour of the text for which I tried to traverse the 2D bounding box matrix and I am comparing the background colour with every colour pixel in the bounding box. Wherever I am getting a colour other than background colour I am returning the colour which would be the font colour.

```
//rectArrayList is an array list of rect for a line in the image 

for(int i=rectArrayList.get(0).left;i<rectArrayList.get(0).right ;i++){
        for(int j=rectArrayList.get(0).top;j<rectArrayList.get(0).bottom;j++){

            pixel=colorbit.getPixel(i,j);
            R = (pixel & 0xff0000) >> 16; //channel the pixel in RGB values
            G = (pixel & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = pixel & 0xff;

//backColour is the background colour of the image 
            if(backColour!=Color.rgb(R,G,B)){ 
                return Color.rgb(R,G,B);
            }

        }
```

Lets say the background colour is a shade of yellow. But while traversing the matrix, I get a different shade of yellow which is background colour behind the font colour and not the font colour. So I get wrong font colour.

I know this technique will fail as the background colour of image would have varying shades of same colour depending on brightness etc.

What should I do to get exact font colour from image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could give you many different solutions to that problem. Here's something simple to start with:

Don't stop when color 1 is unequal color 2. Add some tolerance.
Calculate the Euclidean distance between both RGB tuples. Then check if the distance is bigger than some threshold.
You could also transform RGB to Hue and calculate the absolute difference between both Hue values.

Of course there are more complex and better solutions, but given your knowledge about image processing they would not help you for now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ll try to implement whatever you suggested. But once I am done implementing them, hoping for "those" better and complex solutions from you. Cheers!

Comment: Just a note - Euclidean distance between two color tuples represented as RGB does *not* corresponds to their visual difference. Refer to the YUV space for that.